# Java de-serialization of enums and valueOf

Tags: java, serialization, enums

I've got a distributed system with a serializable enum class with constants that might vary across the system.

Because these classes may be different, valueOf could potentially be called upon deserialization on a constant that doesn't exist, throwing a runtime exception.

I don't believe valueOf can be overridden, or another method custom inserted before valueOf is called during deserialization.

Is there a way to avoid this problem with enums?

Comment: I think it's not entirely clear what you want to do: do you want to de-serialize a given value in the serialized object to different enums depending on some external circumstances ?

Comment: Have you considered adding a custom static method for that? You make it sound like a problem (or even defect) of Enum class, but it's not. The problem is the inconsistent constants.

Comment: I'm looking to prevent deserialization from blowing up upon invoking valueOf on a nonexistent constant.

Comment: @Nikita -- where would I add the static method? Wrapping the valueOf in a safeValueOf method would work in terms of client code, but not the deserialization call to valueOf - can you elaborate?

Comment: @Michael Ok, I see what you want now. What Colin suggested might work: at least, it should work for normal classes.

Comment: Are you by chance deserializing from XML ?

Answer (score 5):

The main problem is the fact that you have enum with inconsistant content on your distributed system. The best thing to do is looking at this first.

A palliative would be to use a readObject() method in your sensitive classes and to catch exceptions dues to bad enum values.

Comment: Thanks -- I'm reading up on readObject() right now -- this is called before valueOf upon deserial?

Comment: This is a method used to rewrite the way your object is deserialized.

Comment: Would this be a problem? "The process by which enum constats are serialized cannot be customized: any class-specific writeObject, readObject... defined by enum types are ignored during serialization and desrialization" http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html

Comment: Or is what you are saying -- override the readObject in the classes that use the enums

Comment: And one other thing! The spring framework which I am using handles the deserialization -- so I may have to modify how the class loader handles this?